# How to rewrite URL for sub domain URL to access main domain pages?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have to show the URL like sub.mydomain.com/pages on adressbar. But the files will excute from mydomain.com/pages..

requirement is to show

sub.mydomain.com/index.html  => index files is on root folder (mydomain.com/index.html)

That means all files are located in root folder but , i am try to showing the URL with subdomain..

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_roxy, mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,P]
```